# How to display Homeslider in all pages in Prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm setting a webshop in Prestashop (1.6.1.1.) using the theme Default-Bootstrap.

I'm using the "Image slider for your homepage" module but it's only displayed in the homepage. I tried different things but any of them worked:

- I've removed the condition `{if $page_name =='index'}`from the /homeslider.tpl
- I've tried to force it by using the following condition in header.tpl:

  `{if $page_name !='index' && $page_name !='pagenotfound'}
     {include file="$tpl_dir./modules/homeslider/homeslider.tpl"}
  {/if}`
- I've tried to copy&paste the code from the /homeslider.tpl directly to the header/tpl template but only the `<!-- Module HomeSlider -->`comments are displayed with anything between (the `{if isset($homeslider_slides)}` condition seems to return false).
- Of course, the module is hooked in the DisplayTop but still nothing happens outside the homepage... and using DisplayTopColumn is not an option.

Here is the code of the homeslider.tpl:

```
<!--{if $page_name =='index'} -->
<!-- Module HomeSlider -->
    {if isset($homeslider_slides)}
        <div id="homepage-slider">
            {if isset($homeslider_slides.0) && isset($homeslider_slides.0.sizes.1)}{capture name='height'}{$homeslider_slides.0.sizes.1}{/capture}{/if}
            <ul id="homeslider"{if isset($smarty.capture.height) && $smarty.capture.height} style="max-height:{$smarty.capture.height}px;"{/if}>
                {foreach from=$homeslider_slides item=slide}
                    {if $slide.active}
                        <li class="homeslider-container">
                            <a href="{$slide.url|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$slide.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <img src="{$link->getMediaLink("`$smarty.const._MODULE_DIR_`homeslider/images/`$slide.image|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'`")}"{if isset($slide.size) && $slide.size} {$slide.size}{else} width="100%" height="100%"{/if} alt="{$slide.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
                            </a>
                            {if isset($slide.description) && trim($slide.description) != ''}
                                <div class="homeslider-description">{$slide.description}</div>
                            {/if}
                        </li>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {/if}
<!-- /Module HomeSlider -->
<!--{/if}-->
```

And a piece of the header.tpl:

```
<div class="header-container">
        <header id="header">
            {capture name='displayBanner'}{hook h='displayBanner'}{/capture}
            {if $smarty.capture.displayBanner}
                <div class="banner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            {$smarty.capture.displayBanner}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/if}
            {capture name='displayNav'}{hook h='displayNav'}{/capture}
            {if $smarty.capture.displayNav}
                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <nav>{$smarty.capture.displayNav}</nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/if}
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="header_logo">
                            <a href="{if isset($force_ssl) && $force_ssl}{$base_dir_ssl}{else}{$base_dir}{/if}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$logo_url}" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{if isset($logo_image_width) && $logo_image_width} width="{$logo_image_width}"{/if}{if isset($logo_image_height) && $logo_image_height} height="{$logo_image_height}"{/if}/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        {if isset($HOOK_TOP)}{$HOOK_TOP}{/if}

                         /*********************************************
                         HERE I'D LIKE TO DISPLAY THE HOMESLIDER MODULE
                         *********************************************/


                        <!--{if $page_name !='index' && $page_name !='pagenotfound'}
                        {include file="$tpl_dir./modules/homeslider/homeslider.tpl"}
                        {/if} -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

I hope I've explained the problem well so you can be able to help me :)

Thanks in advance! 
iarcas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, you foudn the conditional in templates, but have you checked the actual hook in the module?

See this:

**homslider.php**

```
public function hookdisplayTopColumn($params)
{
    if (!isset($this->context->controller->php_self) || $this->context->controller->php_self != 'index')
        return;
    if (!$this->_prepareHook())
        return false;
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'homeslider.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
}
```

So basically, you have to make an override for this function:

**/override/modules/homeslider/homeslider.php**

```
<?php

class HomeSliderOverride extends HomeSlider
{
    public function hookdisplayTopColumn($params)
    {
        if (!$this->_prepareHook())
            return false;
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'homeslider.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @gskema thanks a lot for your answer! I add the override function but it seems not to load the homeslider.css and the homeslider.js (I can only see the image but without animation and styles... Thanks again for your help!